# Deploy Zip File to Azure App Service with az web app deploy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-webapps

As I want to deploy a zip file hosted in a private storage account to Azure App Service by following the method described in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli, I get the following error:

"An error occured during deployment. Status Code: 500, Details: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (The specified resource does not exist.)"

Here is my setup:

- Private Azure Storage account with private endpoint
- Azure App Service with vnet integration

I generate a SAS at container level and run the command az webapp deploy --resource-group  --name  --src-url "https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/sample-container/myapp.zip?SASTOKEN"

Do you have any idea on the cause of this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: can you download the blob with curl? Do you have a vnet integration with route all enabled on your appservice?

Comment: Yes, I can download the blob with curl and Vnet integration with route all is enabled on my app service

Comment: I get now the following error: "An error occured during deployment. Status Code: 500, Details: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Public access is not permitted on this storage account.)"

Comment: to test it further, you could deploy the default placeholder java app (via the portal) and check if you are able to download the package from this app (via ssh/curl in the browser).  Or if you are able to resolve the storage account to the private IP from this app. Cause the error-message sounds like it resolves the public IP to pull from.

Comment: Actually, it was an issue with the console used to run the command, leading to misread the token. Thanks for your help anyway